# How to generate ssh key in linux mint without using terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint

I want to generate **ssh key** but i don't want using terminal is there any way to do that?

I hope there is a GUI to make it

Answer (score 5):

i saw you using linux mint did you have explore the search bar on the bottom if you want to generate ssh keys you can follow this step

1. open the linux mint logo and type "password and keys"
2. open it
3. click the + button and then click add secure shell keys
4. you can follow the step on the GUI there

good lucks if you had a trouble maybe i can add some picture for tutorial